# Make lightning:inputRichText length longer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, richtextarea, lightninginput

Is there a way for the **lightning:inputRichText** to make its size and length longer?

Updated:
[image]
I've already put a style of

> .THIS .lightningInputRichText {
>   height: 500px; }

But as you can see, the editable part was still fixed. How can I adjust the editable part of the lightning:inputrichtext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can easily do by simply adding a height in lightningInputRichText.
when lightning:inputRichText renders on load it have the class with lightningInputRichText and then you can easily override height of that class.

This is working Example-

```
.THIS .lightningInputRichText {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Failed to save undefined: Issue(s) found by CSS Parser (0Ad0n0000009DLg): Expected to find closing brace '}': at line 6, column 1 in '.THIS { } .THIS .lightningInputRichText { »    height: 500px; }' : Source

Receiving this error when trying your code.

Comment: Do you have any other css in there? May be a blank file with .THIS{} ?
If Yes please remove that and add .THIS .lightningInputRichText {
    height: 500px;
}
For more information on how to add css in lightning component please go through this link (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm)

Comment: See updated @Rishi Golyan

Comment: Can you also add one more style
.THIS .slds-rich-text-area__content{
        max-height: 100%;
}

Comment: Maraming Salamat (Thank You very much). It works great. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

For LWC, [per the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation), you can add this to your LWC's css file to adjust height,

```
:host {
--sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
.THIS .slds-rich-text-editor {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **LWC** it's a bit tricky. We solved it by putting the following code into the component that embeds the `<lightning-input-rich-text/>`:

```
// renderedCallback
renderedCallback() {
    this.adjustRichText();
}

adjustRichText() {
    let element = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-rich-text');

    if (!element) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.adjustRichText()
        }, 100);

        return;
    }

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = '.ql-editor.slds-rich-text-area__content {min-height:600px;}';
    element.appendChild(style);
}
```

We need to wait for the rich text to be rendered with a `setTimeout`, and then add a `<style>` element to it.

Known issue: The height of the textarea will change once the user focusses the rich text area.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It retains the side slider when you've added more lines of text.

```
.THIS .ql-editor.slds-rich-text-area__content {min-height:800px;}
```